# Specific regex to highlight links in content in C#

Tags: c#, regex

i found this link http://rickyrosario.com/blog/converting-a-url-into-a-link-in-csharp-using-regular-expressions/ which provide me a function to fit my needs.

This works for:

- www.link.de
- http://www.link.de
- https://www.link.de
- ftp://ftp.link.de

But do not work for

- ftp.link.de

In addition I want to make email clickable as well So I tried this:

```
  const string regexMail = @"(\s|\n|^|\(|\<|\[|\;)(mailto:)?([a-z0-9\.\-_]+@(?:(?:[a-z0-9]+\.|[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+\.)+|[a-z0-9]{2,}\.)*(?:[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+\.)[a-z]{2,6})(\?subject=(\w*))?";
  var rMail = new Regex(regexMail, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  retVal = rMail.Replace(retVal, "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2$3$4\">$2$3$4</a>");
```

As i am a noob in regex I did not manage to make it work. Email content is still not parsed.

Anybody can help to achieve my needs :)? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My not working function (approach):

```
/// <summary>
/// Search content and replace click able content with links and return new click able content
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">any text</param>
/// <returns>any text contaisn click able links</returns>
public string HighlightUrl(string input)
{
  const string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
  var r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  var retVal = r.Replace(input, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");

  // mailto
  const string regexMail = @"(\s|\n|^|\(|\<|\[|\;)(mailto:)?([a-z0-9\.\-_]+@(?:(?:[a-z0-9]+\.|[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+\.)+|[a-z0-9]{2,}\.)*(?:[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+\.)[a-z]{2,6})(\?subject=(\w*))?";
  var rMail = new Regex(regexMail, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  retVal = rMail.Replace(retVal, "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2$3$4\">$2$3$4</a>");

  return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
const string regex = @"(((www|ftp)\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
```

It might work ... :)

Comment: ok for the ftp.link.de thing this helps. but I had to add ftp:// in the .Replace tag as well... Now only the mailto: thingy left :)